# Querying large MySQL tables with Amazon RDS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a table with about 2.2 million rows and on the table I am trying to pull a query with a few joins. One of those joins is a subquery. I've optimized it as much as can short of completely re-writing the app code.

Here is the results of `EXPLAIN()` from this particular query:

[image: My explain query]

As I've highlighted in red, there are a lot of records to go through in the click table. Row #4 is my subquery join, but running my own tests the slowness seems to come from that giant table.

So, I am looking at my provisioned IOPS and latency in Amazon CloudWatch when I ran this query:

[image: CloudWatch]

Looking at this, is it fair to say that I need more Provisioned IOPS? I only have 1,000 at the moment.

I really do know know what else to do here.

I am also wondering - I have a read replica on this RDS, would it make sense to run this query on the read replica in a queue so that my main DB does not affect performance on production?

Comment: Add the proper indexes. Put in some db caching on particular queries you know will be run a lot....make a view rather than just doing a query with a join....

Comment: Show the table schema information and query you are running first.  Before even worrying about the hardware, you need to make sure your query is optimized. WRT the read replica question. Yes absolutely use it.  That is what read replicas are for - to shift heavy read loads off the master.

Comment: @developerwjk I will look into the caching, thanks. Regarding the view, wouldn't that still slow things down? I would think that view needs to be re-run after the source tables are updated in some way, no? I am thinking that would kill performance.

Comment: @MikeBrant I'd like the assume that the query is optimized. I am not that worried about adding hardware as my costs for that would be much lower than rebuilding the necessary code. With that said, I do not want to add hardware if it won't impact performance in the positive.

Comment: @Alex Markov, I don't know about in mysql, but in Microsoft a view with a join seems to run faster than just a query with a join. MySQL has a way to turn on caching in a config file. You can set it to cache everything or only cache queries marked for caching, and then use `select SQL_CACHE ...` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/query-cache-in-select.html

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to create a read replica and offload all of these lengthy queries to there.

Most of these queries are for client reporting and when clients have a lot of clicks in the DB, the page ran for a long time and eventually timed out. So, using this read replica, I've created a report queue system using a cron job. Instead of giving them the report on the fly, I just queue it up and email it to them when it is ready from the read replica. Problem solved! I hope.